# Magento 2 Api Getting Error '%fieldName is a required field'?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, postman

I am not getting result **(id)** while using **POST** method using url is **rest/V1/hello/test/3**

**Screenshot**: [image]

I have followed this link [For Reference Please Click Here](http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/)

> 1) webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
        <route url="/V1/hello/name/:name" method="GET">
            <service class="Inchoo\Hello\Api\HelloInterface" method="name"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
        </route>
        <route url="/V1/hello/test/:test" method="POST">
            <service class="Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface" method="test"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
        </route>
    </routes>
```

> 2) TestInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Hello\Api;

interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param id $name Users id.
     * @return id Greeting message with users id.
     */
    public function test($id);
}
```

> 3) Test.php

```
<?php
namespace Inchoo\Hello\Model;
use Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface;

class Test implements TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $name Users name.
     * @return string Greeting message with users name.
     */
    public function test($id) {
        return "Hello How are you your id is:," .$id;
    }
}
```

> 4) di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Inchoo\Hello\Api\HelloInterface" type="Inchoo\Hello\Model\Hello" />
    <preference for="Inchoo\Hello\Api\TestInterface" type="Inchoo\Hello\Model\Test" />
</config>
```

Now i cleared cache and pagecache and opened the postmen app and kept the url like http://10.0.0.33/nagarajuM2/rest/V1/hello/test/3

but i am getting error.

Please help me out.

Comment: You are Sending POST request and in that what data you are sending ?

Comment: Actually i want to print id value using post method hence i have used the same concept what ever inchoo has followed. and in the url i am using like  rest/V1/hello/name/4

Comment: For print first you have to send in POST data like json:{ "id": {}}

Comment: ok let me try..

Comment: Thanks @Emipro technologies now i got the result. thanks for u help.  http://prntscr.com/g0d53x

Comment: Please post u r answer i will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are Sending POST Request so you also have to send data in POST request in json format like :`{ "id": {}}`

And have to set `Content-Type:application/json` in http header.

Comment: As well as we have to mention “Content-Type:application/json” i the header section  http://prntscr.com/g0d96z

Answer (score 6):

Update the function comments correctly for both Interface file and class that implement it.

```
interface TestInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns greeting message to user
     *
     * @param int $name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function test($id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same issues, then I noticed that **I was using POST instead of GET**, changing it the issues were solved.